# How to handle UILabel inside UITableViewCell using auto layout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, autolayout

How to handle UILabel inside UITableViewCell using auto layout ? according to the length of that label .. this is my view :

[image]

I want the blue label to be in the center but without crossing the neighbor label in the same cell if it's long.

I added constraints between them but it wouldn't be in the center.

Any good constraints for this type of cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets name the labels as `title_label` and `detail_label` i.e in your 3rd cell 'service' is title and the other long label is detail.

I.   Set the leading space of title_label to superview set the constant as per your need. and create its outlet let it be `constraint_title_leading`.

II.  Set center vertically in container for `title_label`.

III. Now set the leading space of `detail_label` to the trailing of `title_label`. Let the constant be 8 points. Create an outlet let its name be `constraint_detail_leading`

IV.  Set detail_label to be vertically center w.r.t `title_label` OR superview.

VI.   Set `detail_label`'s content alignment to center.

VII.  Set the trailing space of the detail label to superview dont care about the its constant we will change it in code. Let its name be `constraint_detail_trailing`

VIII. After setting the datasource of the cell call this method.

```
func adjustConstraints() -> Void {


   let titleWidth =   (self.title_label.text! as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(600, 600), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, 
    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : self.title_label.font], context: nil).width 

    self.constraint_detail_trailing.constant = self.constraint_title_leading.constant + titleWidth + self.constraint_detail_leading.constant 
    self.layoutIfNeeded() 
}
```

To enable multiline i.e dynamic height of the rows, instead of center constraint of `detail_label` pin it to top and bottom w.r.t superview such that top constant equals bottom constant and set its `numberOfLines` to be 0. And set `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Answer (score 0):

Add a leading margin of choice (10px) constraint on your blue label related to your "service" label

Answer (score 0):

Remove the horizantol center constraint on the label and add a leading/trailing constraint to it. Then set text justification as center for the UILabel.

Note that you should also have the top and bottom constraints on the UILabel. And only top constraint for the "Service" UILabel.

Comment: Thanks for answering but still having problem

Comment: wht was the results? you may need to add your code.